# How do I integrate exponential functions including $e^{x^2}$?

Tags: integration

I am trying to prove the following equality:

$$\lambda\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\mathrm df}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(i2\pi f(x-a)\right)\exp\left(\frac{-i\pi\lambda tf^2}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2\pi it}{n\lambda}}}\exp\left(\frac{i\pi n(x-a)^2}{\lambda t}\right)$$

but am struggling to work out which method to use. I assume somewhere in this I need to use

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-f^2}\,\mathrm df=\sqrt{\pi}$$

but I haven't currently got much further than that, can anyone advise on this?

Comment: This is literally written in the most cumbersome way possible

Comment: Write the exponent as a quadratic function in $f$ and complete the square. Then by a shift of the variable you will get to the desired result.

Comment: Following the suggestion by @YvesDaoust it boils down to $$\int_{\mathbb R} \exp\left(-i \pi c \left(\left(f+\frac{d}{2c}\right)^2-\frac{d^2}{4c^2}\right)\right)\,\mathrm df,$$ where $c=\frac{\lambda t}n$ and $d=2a-2x$ which is easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ax^2+bx+c}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{a(x-b/2a)^2+c-b^2/4a}\,dx=e^{c-b^2/4a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ax^2}\,dx.$$